# SQL subquery Total/Count

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that lists the name of a manager and the number of people they manage.

In the `Manager` table we have the managers `name` and `id`.

In the `Employee` table we have the employees `name`, `id` and `managerID`.

I don't understand how to get the count of the employees that a manager manages.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know how to get the count of employees by manager ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(e.EmpID), m.ManagerID
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Manager m 
ON e.ManagerID= m.ManagerID
GROUP BY m.ManagerID
```

Comment: Any reason you're joining the manager table when you're not using any values from it?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, it's generally considered rude to edit code (and will open you up mistakes). In this case the suggested edit you approved was incorrect. You can't alias a column as a string. Please _only_ approve suggested edits to code if you're _certain_ that it is correct. If you have no knowledge of a subject you can click the "Not Sure" button.

Comment: @Ben: I certainly have knowledge higher than "none". Except for the "name" versus "managerid", I certainly was sure that this suggested edit was positive, as the original question asked for "count+name", not "count+id", and the edit suggested such exact change. The suggested edit incorrectly changed Group-By to by-name which is not the same as by-id, so I merged them together on the fly. Aliasing is possible, as "quotes" and [brackets] are treated the same, at least in SqlServer (dialect was not specified). I do however overlook apostrophes/quotes though, but this is a "typo" error class.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.Name, COUNT(e.id) AS NumberOfEmployeesManaged
FROM Manager m INNER JOIN Employee e ON m.id = e.managerID
GROUP BY m.Name
```

That should do it I think, just a simple count of the employee ids after joining the manager and employee tables, grouped on manager name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(emp.empid), mgr.managerid
FROM Employee emp
INNER JOIN Manager mgr ON emp.managerid=mgr.managerid
GROUP BY mgr.managerid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use the COUNT aggregator in a JOIN.  But you can run 2 queries.  One would select the manager's name & id.  The 2nd would look like this:

$id = the manager's id

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee WHERE managerID=$id
```

Alternately, you could not use COUNT and run a query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM Employee WHERE managerID=$id
```

Then the # of resulting rows would be the count of employees managed by the manager.